# how can we add link in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to add a link on Angular 8 but I don't know how to do it.

example link : https://stackoverflow.com

I use routerLink or app-routing.module ?

```
<div class="background-color">
<h1>Mes Projets</h1>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="div1">
        <img class="img" src="/assets/img/catmash.jpg" alt="projet1">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">
                <h3>Langages utilisé :</h3>
                <hr>
                <p>Angular 8</p>
                <h3>Lien :</h3>
                <hr>
                <button [routerLink]="https://stackoverflow.com">
                    Accedez au site
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <img src="/assets/img/angular.jpg" alt="projet2">
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
        <img src="/assets/img/angular.jpg" alt="projet3">
    </div>
    <div class="div4">
        <img src="/assets/img/angular.jpg" alt="projet4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot use routerLink for external links. Use <a href="https://stackoverflow.com"> for these kind of cases.

Comment: Why are you using a button for a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RouterLink doesn't support external URLS yet.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24567

I think you could use href instead RouterLink in that case.